# C: integral-promotion versus integer-promotion

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I just created the tag `integral-promotion` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4001630/100754) because, AFAIK, that is the formal name for the concept. However, I see that an `integer-promotion` tag already exists and is used to refer to the same concept.

I am not trying to collect more badges or anything, but I think it would be appropriate to retag those questions to use `integral-promotion` rather than `integer-promotion`. Does that make sense?

I have already [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/integer-promotion/synonyms) `integral-promotion` as a [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/integer-promotion/synonyms) for `integer-promotion`.

Comment: It's a shame `[usual-arithmetic-conversions]` is too long, that would make a much better category.

Answer (score 3):

<s>C actually uses *integer promotion* (C99 6.3.1.1/2).</s>

C90 uses *integral promotion* (C90 3.2.1.1).  C99 changed the wording and replaced most instances of *integral* with *integer*, so it uses *integer promotions* (C99 6.3.1.1/2).  The only time *integral* appears in C99 is when referring to the integral and fractional parts of a floating point number.

C++ uses *integral promotion* (C++03 4.5).

I agree that they should be synonyms, but which one is the "primary" tag doesn't really matter.  Both are correct and mean the same thing.  However, some people (especially beginners) tend to get tripped up by the word "integral" (not that that's a spectacular reason not to use it...)

Comment: Apparently, my brain is mushier than I thought. I could have sworn "integral promotion" was C terminology. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: @Sinan:  Actually, I was half wrong; C90 does in fact use _integral promotion_.  The language was changed in C99.  *sigh*

Answer (score 3):

With due respect to the C++ committee, an integral is the thing in calculus signified by the extra tall "S" thingy. I much prefer [integer-promotion].